# Looping over directories and creating text file that include specific type of files names within each directory

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to find all .mp4 files starting with the letter S in every subdirectory, and list them in a text file in each subdirectory with its full path.

```
for f in ./*;  do  (cd “$f”; printf "file ‘$PWD/%s’\n” S*.mp4>mylist.txt ); done;
```

But this only leaves me with

```
>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your cut'n'paste has a mixture of normal quotes and "smart" quotes (eg in the `cd` command, and at the end of the `printf`).  If this is an accurate paste from your command then this will be the cause of your problem.  Replacing them with normal quotes allowed the command to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put subdirectories names in a file called `names.txt`, then use the command `find` within the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd  parent_directory
ls -d */ >names.txt

for i in $(cat names.txt); do
    cd ${i}
    find $PWD -type f -name "S*.mp4" > outputfile.txt

    cd ..   
done
```

Comment: You don't need a round-trip to a file if you just use `for i in */`. Also, this particular solution will make the shell split directory names that contain spaces.